# How do I run this function for multiple values of N?

Tags: python

I am trying to run the code below for `N = np.linspace(20,250,47)`, but I get multiple errors when trying to change the `N`. I am new to python and am not sure how to get multiple values of this function using multiple values of N. Below is the code with `N = 400` and it does work, but I am not sure how to make it work for multiple `N`'s at the same time.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

S0 = 9
K = 10
T = 3
r = 0.06
sigma = 0.3
N = 400
dt = T / N
u = exp(sigma*sqrt(dt)+(r-0.5*sigma**2)*dt)
d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(dt)+(r-0.5*sigma**2)*dt)
p = 0.5

def binomial_tree_put(N, T, S0, sigma, r, K, array_out=False):
    dt = T / N
    u = exp(sigma*sqrt(dt)+(r-0.5*sigma**2)*dt)
    d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(dt)+(r-0.5*sigma**2)*dt)
    p = 0.5
    
    price_tree = np.zeros([N+1,N+1])

    for i in range(N+1):
        for j in range(i+1):
            price_tree[j,i] = S0*(d**j)*(u**(i-j))

    option = np.zeros([N+1,N+1])
    option[:,N] = np.maximum(np.zeros(N+1), K - price_tree[:,N])
    
    for i in np.arange(N-1, -1, -1):
        for j in np.arange(0, i+1):
            option[j, i] = np.exp(-r*dt)*(p*option[j, i+1]+(1-p)*option[j+1, i+1])
            
    if array_out:
        return [option[0,0], price_tree, option]
    else:
        return option[0,0]
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps at me is the usage of `np.zeros(N+1)` and `range(N+1)` in several places. Those won't work if you send N that has more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

`np.linspace()` creates an np.array but the function expects a sinlge integer. If you want to execute a function for each element contained inside a array/list, you can do that inside a loop like this:

```python
# your code as defined above goes here

for num in np.linspace(20,250,47):
    N = int(num)      # you could just put N in the line above - this is just to illustrate
    binomial_tree_put(N, T, S0, sigma, r, K, array_out=False)
```

Be aware, depending on how long your function takes to execute and how many elements are in your iterable (e.g. 47 for your case), it may take a while to execute.

Edit: I also noticed you seem to be missing an import in your example code. `exp()` and `sqrt()` are part of the `math` module.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list of values for `N` e.g `N = [400, 300, 500, 800]`, then you need to call the function for every value, you can use a loop for that.
For example,

```
for num in N:
    binomial_tree_put(num, *other arguments*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `partial` function, like this:

```py
from functools import partial

N = [1, 2, ...]  # all your N values

binom_fct = partial(binomial_tree_put, T=T, S0=S0, sigma=sigma, r=r, K=K, array_out=array_out)
for num in N:
    binom_fct(num)
```

partial help [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)